# syntax error or access violation 1064

Tags: php

getting (syntax error or access violation 1064) dont know what is the problem. why i am getting this error?

```
public function sc($sc)
{
    try
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_qr FROM temp WHERE user_qr :qr");
        $stmt->execute(array(':qr'=>$sc));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {

            if($sc==$userRow['user_qr'])
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;


            }
        }

    }
```

getting (syntax error or access violation 1064)

Comment: You forgot your equals sign

Comment: ohhh i got it thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_qr FROM temp WHERE user_qr :qr");
                                                                    ^here
```

You forgot your equals sign in the query, change your statement to:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_qr FROM temp WHERE  user_qr = :qr");
```